# Is Kiwi low or high fructose?

Tags: data, healthcare-data, fructose

It's ridiculous: on some websites I see info that it is low fructose and on the other it is high fructose (not even moderate).
[Here](http://www.wch.sa.gov.au/services/az/other/nutrition/documents/Low_fructose_factsheet.pdf) for example it goes as high in fructose.
And [here](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=low%20fructose%20fruits&meta=) it goes as low.
Are there known reliable source ?

Comment: Hmmm... the Australian Department of Health vs. happysugarhabits.com and a couple of other media sites. I'm going to bet on the Australian government but it is a legit question. The discrepancies are disturbing.

Comment: Are you asking this from the perspective of fructose malabsorption?

Comment: @Jan yes, I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [NutritionData](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/fruits-and-fruit-juices/1934/2) (data from US Department of Agriculture - USDA.gov), 100 g of kiwi fruit contains **4.4 g fructose** and 4.1 g glucose. The [wch.sa.gov.au](http://www.wch.sa.gov.au/services/az/other/nutrition/documents/Low_fructose_factsheet.pdf) site in the question lists kiwi as high in fructose based on their criteria (2.5-5% of fructose = high). But they also say it has a favorable fructose/glucose ratio, so it will be "better tolerated" by individuals with fructose malabsorption (FM).

Individuals with FM are advised to avoid fructose, but it is not really the absolute amount of fructose, but a high fructose/glucose (F/G) ratio that is problematic. F/G ratio for kiwi fruit is 1.07, which is similar to sucrose (F/G = 1), which [should cause no problems](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3471321/), because [every molecule of glucose helps to absorb one molecule of fructose](http://www.wch.sa.gov.au/services/az/other/nutrition/documents/Low_fructose_factsheet.pdf). For comparison, [apples](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/fruits-and-fruit-juices/1809/2), which are known to trigger bloating and diarrhea in individuals with FM, have 5.9 g of fructose/100 g, and a high F/G ratio: 2.45.

The actual F/G ratio in a certain kiwi fruit may vary due to the kiwi variety, season, ripeness, etc. On the end, you need to rely on your own experience.